# DOM does not remove item after state update and Delete in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been baffled as to why an item - `card` does not disappear from the DOM after deletion and state update. My edit function works fine and I've soured my code for spelling errors and wrong variables, etc.

Here's my App (top component) state object:

```
state = {
  decks: [],
  cards: [],
  selectedCards: [],
  selectedDecks: [],
  currentUser: null,
  users: []
}
```

my Delete function (optimistic)  in App that gets passed down to a `deckLayout` component:

```
deleteCard = (cardId, deckId) => {
  const cardCopy = this.state.cards.slice()
  const foundOldCardIdx = cardCopy.findIndex(card => card.id === cardId)
  cardCopy.splice(foundOldCardIdx, 1)
  this.setState({
    cards: cardCopy
  }, console.log(this.state.cards, cardCopy))
  this.filterCards(deckId)
  console.log(this.state.cards)
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/v1/cards/${cardId}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
};
```

And this is a `filterCards` functions that gets called after Delete and State update (this works for Edit):

```
filterCards = (deckId) => {
  if (this.state.cards.length === 0) {
    alert('No cards yet!')
  } else {
    const filteredCards = this.state.cards.filter(card => card.deck_id === deckId)
    this.setState({
      selectedCards: filteredCards
    })
    this.filterDecks()
  }
};
```

which then calls a `filterDecks` function:

```
filterDecks = () => {
  if (this.state.currentUser) {
    const filteredDecks = this.state.decks.filter(deck => {
      return deck.user_id === this.state.currentUser.id
    })
    this.setState({
      selectedDecks: filteredDecks
    })
  } else {
    alert('Login or sign up')
  }
};
```

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out? Based on the code you provided, I don't see any error.

Comment: I'm at a loss here. My edit function works perfect and mirrors the delete except for the 3rd parameter in the splice() function because it's not adding anything.